Weston window manager closes HDMI connection after few minutes - Why?
I have an STM32MP151 (none GPU) processor and I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. When I start up the weston window manager, everything seems to work. But there are two problems:

No mouse cursor
The HDMI quit the connection to the TV screen after few minutes

First, I have no USB mouse connected. Second, the HDMI losing its connection when unexpectedly large timestamp jump appears.
Why questions are simple: Why does my HDMI lose its connection and why can't I see any mouse pointer at the screen?
2004hroot@stm32-os:~# weston
[?2004l
Date: 2024-04-19 UTC
[16:41:40.-1097362864] weston 13.0.0
               https://wayland.freedesktop.org
               Bug reports to: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wayland/weston/issues/
               Build: 13.0.0
[16:41:40.-1226351923] Command line: weston
[16:41:40.-1226351867] OS: Linux, 6.1.82, #1 PREEMPT Tue Sep 10 21:04:28 CEST 2024, armv7l
[16:41:40.091] Flight recorder: enabled
[16:41:40.-1226351867] Starting with no config file.
[16:41:40.000] Output repaint window is 7 ms maximum.
[16:41:41.-1097366632] Loading module '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libweston-13/drm-backend.so'
[16:41:41.1374389535] initializing drm backend
[16:41:41.192349952] Trying libseat launcher...
[16:41:41.000] [libseat/libseat.c:73] Seat opened with backend 'seatd'
[16:41:41.192349952] [libseat/backend/seatd.c:212] Enabling seat
[16:41:41.192349952] libseat: session control granted
[16:41:41.4295896] using /dev/dri/card0
[16:41:41.-1226351867] DRM: supports atomic modesetting
[16:41:41.-1226351867] DRM: supports GBM modifiers
[16:41:41.-1226351867] DRM: does not support async page flipping
[16:41:41.065] DRM: supports picture aspect ratio
[16:41:47.-1097366856] Loading module '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libweston-13/gl-renderer.so'
[16:41:47.4633696] warning: failed to query rendering device from EGL
[16:41:47.000] EGL version: 1.5
[16:41:47.-1226351867] EGL vendor: Mesa Project
[16:41:47.-1226351867] EGL client APIs: OpenGL OpenGL_ES 
[16:41:47.-1097363424] warning: Disabling render GPU timeline and explicit synchronization due to missing EGL_ANDROID_native_fence_sync extension
[16:41:47.146] EGL features:
               EGL Wayland extension: no
               context priority: no
               buffer age: yes
               partial update: no
               swap buffers with damage: no
               configless context: yes
               surfaceless context: yes
               dmabuf support: modifiers
[16:41:48.-1225390907] GL version: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.1
[16:41:48.072] GLSL version: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
[16:41:48.-1226351867] GL vendor: Mesa
[16:41:48.-1226351867] GL renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 17.0.6, 128 bits)
[16:41:48.069] GL ES 3.2 - renderer features:
               read-back format: ARGB8888
               glReadPixels supports y-flip: yes
               wl_shm 10 bpc formats: yes
               wl_shm 16 bpc formats: yes
               wl_shm half-float formats: yes
               internal R and RG formats: yes
               OES_EGL_image_external: yes
[16:41:48.-1225439344] Using GL renderer
[16:41:48.000] event0  - pmic_onkey: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[16:41:48.068] event0  - pmic_onkey: device is a keyboard
[16:41:48.000] libinput: configuring device "pmic_onkey".
[16:41:48.000] DRM: head 'HDMI-A-1' found, connector 32 is connected, EDID make 'TCL', model 'TCL SMART TV', serial '69649'
               Supported EOTF modes: SDR
[16:41:48.000] Registered plugin API 'weston_drm_output_api_v1' of size 20
[16:41:48.075] Registered plugin API 'weston_drm_virtual_output_api_v2' of size 24
[16:41:48.083] Color manager: no-op
[16:41:48.-1097363152] Output 'HDMI-A-1' attempts EOTF mode: SDR
[16:41:48.-1097363152] Output 'HDMI-A-1' using color profile: stock sRGB color profile
[16:41:48.004] Chosen EGL config details: id:  31 rgba: 8 8 8 0 buf: 24 dep:  0 stcl: 0 int: 1-1 type: win vis_id: XRGB8888 (0x34325258)
[16:41:48.4665584] Output HDMI-A-1 (crtc 38) video modes:
               1920x1080@30.0 16:9, current, 74.2 MHz
               1920x1080@25.0 16:9, 74.2 MHz
               1920x1080@24.0 16:9, 74.2 MHz
               1280x720@60.0, 74.2 MHz
               1280x720@60.0 16:9, 74.2 MHz
               1280x720@50.0 16:9, 74.2 MHz
               720x576@50.0 16:9, 27.0 MHz
               720x576@50.0 4:3, 27.0 MHz
               720x480@59.9 16:9, 27.0 MHz
               720x480@59.9 4:3, 27.0 MHz
[16:41:48.1213014064] associating input device event0 with output HDMI-A-1 (none by udev)
[16:41:48.-1097363136] Output 'HDMI-A-1' enabled with head(s) HDMI-A-1
[16:41:48.038] Compositor capabilities:
               arbitrary surface rotation: yes
               screen capture uses y-flip: yes
               cursor planes: yes
               arbitrary resolutions: no
               view mask clipping: yes
               explicit sync: no
               color operations: yes
               presentation clock: CLOCK_MONOTONIC, id 1
               presentation clock resolution: 0.000000001 s
[16:41:48.-1097366584] Loading module '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/weston/desktop-shell.so'
[16:41:48.-1225664848] launching '/usr/libexec/weston-keyboard'
[16:41:48.064] launching '/usr/libexec/weston-desktop-shell'
[16:41:50.-1236052069] Warning: computed repaint delay for output [HDMI-A-1] is abnormal: -75284 msec
could not load cursor 'dnd-move'
could not load cursor 'dnd-copy'
could not load cursor 'dnd-none'
could not load cursor 'dnd-move'
could not load cursor 'dnd-copy'
could not load cursor 'dnd-none'
[16:46:51.-1097363680] unexpectedly large timestamp jump (from 373272 to 374939)

When I use pixman instead, lots of warnings disapear at the beginning. But still, no mouse cursor and the HDMI is lost its connection after few minutes. I don't know if it has to do with no USB mouse is connected or not.
weston --use-pixman
[?2004l
Date: 2024-04-19 UTC
[17:42:19.-1094577600] weston 13.0.0
               https://wayland.freedesktop.org
               Bug reports to: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wayland/weston/issues/
               Build: 13.0.0
[17:42:19.-1226704179] Command line: weston --use-pixman
[17:42:19.-1226704123] OS: Linux, 6.1.82, #1 PREEMPT Tue Sep 10 21:04:28 CEST 2024, armv7l
[17:42:19.091] Flight recorder: enabled
[17:42:19.-1226704123] Starting with no config file.
[17:42:19.000] Output repaint window is 7 ms maximum.
[17:42:19.-1094581368] Loading module '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libweston-13/drm-backend.so'
[17:42:19.1374389535] initializing drm backend
[17:42:19.-19123200] Trying libseat launcher...
[17:42:19.000] [libseat/libseat.c:73] Seat opened with backend 'seatd'
[17:42:19.-19123200] [libseat/backend/seatd.c:212] Enabling seat
[17:42:19.-19123200] libseat: session control granted
[17:42:19.4775120] using /dev/dri/card0
[17:42:19.-1226704123] DRM: supports atomic modesetting
[17:42:19.-1226704123] DRM: supports GBM modifiers
[17:42:19.-1226704123] DRM: does not support async page flipping
[17:42:19.065] DRM: supports picture aspect ratio
[17:42:19.000] Using Pixman renderer
[17:42:19.000] event0  - pmic_onkey: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[17:42:19.068] event0  - pmic_onkey: device is a keyboard
[17:42:19.000] libinput: configuring device "pmic_onkey".
[17:42:19.000] DRM: head 'HDMI-A-1' found, connector 32 is connected, EDID make 'TCL', model 'TCL SMART TV', serial '69649'
               Supported EOTF modes: SDR
[17:42:19.000] Registered plugin API 'weston_drm_output_api_v1' of size 20
[17:42:19.075] Registered plugin API 'weston_drm_virtual_output_api_v2' of size 24
[17:42:19.083] Color manager: no-op
[17:42:19.-1094577888] Output 'HDMI-A-1' attempts EOTF mode: SDR
[17:42:19.-1094577888] Output 'HDMI-A-1' using color profile: stock sRGB color profile
[17:42:19.000] DRM: output HDMI-A-1 uses shadow framebuffer.
[17:42:19.544698212] Output HDMI-A-1 (crtc 38) video modes:
               1920x1080@30.0 16:9, current, 74.2 MHz
               1920x1080@25.0 16:9, 74.2 MHz
               1920x1080@24.0 16:9, 74.2 MHz
               1280x720@60.0, 74.2 MHz
               1280x720@60.0 16:9, 74.2 MHz
               1280x720@50.0 16:9, 74.2 MHz
               720x576@50.0 16:9, 27.0 MHz
               720x576@50.0 4:3, 27.0 MHz
               720x480@59.9 16:9, 27.0 MHz
               720x480@59.9 4:3, 27.0 MHz
[17:42:19.1213014064] associating input device event0 with output HDMI-A-1 (none by udev)
[17:42:19.-1094577872] Output 'HDMI-A-1' enabled with head(s) HDMI-A-1
[17:42:19.002] Compositor capabilities:
               arbitrary surface rotation: yes
               screen capture uses y-flip: no
               cursor planes: yes
               arbitrary resolutions: no
               view mask clipping: yes
               explicit sync: no
               color operations: no
               presentation clock: CLOCK_MONOTONIC, id 1
               presentation clock resolution: 0.000000001 s
[17:42:19.-1094581320] Loading module '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/weston/desktop-shell.so'
[17:42:19.-1226017104] launching '/usr/libexec/weston-keyboard'
[17:42:19.064] launching '/usr/libexec/weston-desktop-shell'
[17:42:19.-1236404325] Warning: computed repaint delay for output [HDMI-A-1] is abnormal: -75339 msec
could not load cursor 'dnd-move'
could not load cursor 'dnd-copy'
could not load cursor 'dnd-none'
could not load cursor 'dnd-move'
could not load cursor 'dnd-copy'
could not load cursor 'dnd-none'


Here is the answer
weston --use-pixman --idle-time=0

I'm missing the weston.ini file. Don't know where it is in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS :(
